# NLCD Data Processing in QGIS 3+

Tags: qgis, raster, nlcd

Firstly, sorry for having to post this question, I feel like I've been going in circles trying to make sense of similar questions. I'm quite new to QGIS so please do re-direct this if needed.

**Why I want to do** I want to crop the NLCD data raster, e.g. `Raster -> Extraction -> Clip Raster by Mask Layer` so I can do some very basic counting of land-types on a per-county basis. This in itself seems to cause issues as the Raster data is just so big. So if there is some other method that I am unaware, please let me know. Otherwise, please read on.

**Background:** Like many that have come before me, I have been using the [NLCD Land Cover CONUS Data set for the US](https://www.mrlc.gov/data?f%5B0%5D=category%3Aland%20cover&f%5B1%5D=region%3Aconus&f%5B2%5D=region%3Anorth%20america). This provides a pretty large set of files (~20 GB per year), of which a erdas .img file is easily created in QGIS (drag and drop). In the metadata file, this has the projection:

`PROJCS["Albers_Conical_Equal_Area",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Albers"],PARAMETER["false_easting",0.0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0.0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-96.0],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",29.5],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",45.5],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",23.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]`

Next to this, we have the [US 2017 Census County Shapefiles](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2017-nation-u-s-current-county-and-equivalent-national-shapefile). Again this is easily entered into QGIS with a drag and drop. This has the projection:

`GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]`

**Problem Summary**: Default QGIS CRS is 4326. I load in the NLCD data, set the NLCD layer CRS to EPSG:102003 (Albers). I then set the project CRS to the same. Then loading in the Shapefiles for the US County data, I get the image below. Showing that the layers are offset.

[image: NLCD Data & Shapefiles Layer]

I feel like the issue [could relate to the problems as described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324244/projecting-nlcd-data-as-wgs84-using-qgis) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182975/clipping-a-raster-with-a-shape-layer-fails-by-returning-an-empty-raster-nan-0/183080) but I'm not exactly sure what is going wrong in my process. Further, my data is so big that any warping seems to take forever on my laptop.

Am I just missing something obvious?